# Action of the $n$-th roots of unity on $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

The following appears as **Example 1.9.5** (c) in Fulton's *Intersection theory*.

> Let $X$ be the quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2$ obtained by identifying $(s,0)$ with $(\mu s,0)$ for all $n$-th roots of unity $\mu$; equivalently, $$X = \operatorname{Spec} K[s^n, st, s^2t, \dotsc, s^{n-1}t, t].$$

I don't understand how the $n$-th roots of unity can only act on the line $\{t = 0\}$, what happens to a general point $(s, t)$? But if $$\mu(s, t) = (\mu s, t),$$ then I don't see why $s\cdot t$ should be an invariant.

Or is Fulton not talking about group actions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a group action on the whole of $\Bbb A^2$, because $\mu$ doesn't act on points with nonzero $t$-coordinate. It might help you to think about an example: taking $n=2$, we're looking at $\operatorname{Spec} k[s^2,st,t]$. As $k[s^2,st,t]\cong k[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz^2)$, we're looking at the Whitney umbrella, which you can think about as grabbing the left half-plane, twisting it, and shoving it through the right-half plane so the positive and negative $x$-axes are overlapping. We can see that when we do this, we preserve all the points which aren't on the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the connection to the Whitney umbrella, I missed that, although it was example 1.9.5. (b) :-D